# Handle special character while doing copy paste a sentence from any source to JSF text box or text area

Tags: jsf, character-encoding, copy, paste

I have one issue while trying to copy paste the content from word or outlook into the JSF textarea. I had problem in viewing the particular aphostrohe('). Some other Symbols are getting replaced instead of that. I have character encoding of ISO-8859-1 at the application level. I have included the following code in the particular page where the text area resides. Still the symbol is there.

I tried to add the following coding to encode this from bean level. This code encodes and i can able to see the aphostrophe(') in the text. But then if i insert the same text, some other symbol is getting inserted into the DB. Is there is any thing needs to be changed in hibernate.

new String(text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8").

Please share any solution to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

> *I have character encoding of ISO-8859-1 at the application level.*

There is your problem. Any characters which are not covered by ISO-8859-1 can impossibly be changed to be covered by ISO-8859-1. As to your particular case with quotation marks, in Wikipedia you can find a list of [all quotation mark characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_Unicode). The ones beyond `U+00FF` range are not covered by ISO-8859-1. Microsoft applications like Outlook, Word, etc use "curved quotes" which are in the `U+2xxx` range and thus would appear as [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) when encoded using ISO-8859-1.

ISO-8859-1 is a rather inferior character encoding from the prehistory which supports [only 255 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Codepage_layout) and is definitely not prepared for world domination. The world knows *many more* characters than ISO-8859-1 can ever cover. You should be using an Unicode based character encoding like UTF-8. Unicode definies and supports [over 1 million of characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout).

You should change your application to use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1. Note that JSF 2.x by default already supports and uses UTF-8. Your concrete problem thus indicates that you're using JSF 1.x, or that you have manually changed it. You should not do that and set everything to UTF-8, including the database tables. Some helpful hints can be found in this blog: [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to UNICODE on your server side, For example if your using glassfish add parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" entry to your glassfish-web.xml. Worked for me.

`<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />`